# How can Microsoft Edge Browser run a downloaded exe file while beeing an UWP Application?

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, microsoft-edge, windows-community-toolkit

During development of an universal windows platform app we faced a lot of limitations in terms of isolation coming with the UWP platform e.g. the restriction of not being able to launch any exe file from within an UWP App.

From what I can see, Microsoft Edge Browser is a UWP App. How is it possible that Edge can download and launch an exe file from the web and execute it, as this is some of the most important restrictions of the UWP platform?

Is Edge not a true UWP App ?

**Update 1:**

- Looks like the Settings App in Windows 10 is also an UWP App and does control things, that UWP Apps can't do by design. Also not a true UWP App ?

Comment: As I think about the authors of Edge and Settings it's not weird for me that those apps can do variety of things that normal developers can dream about.

Comment: I'd rather say that Edge and the Settings, as well as the Music and the Store app are OS provided applications. They are so called "trusted Windows store apps", providing a basic user experience and therefore having some special traits.

Comment: Is the term "trusted Windows store apps" actually an official term for such apps? For some of those apps its even more misleading as they are not in the store at all. What I would be interested in is kind of an official statement how those apps get around this limitation and if Microsoft considers these apps as true UWP. I wonder if the fact that Edge is not in the windows store (and coupled to windows releases), is tied to this circumstances and therefore means, that such an app will never be in the store. Edge in the store, frequently updating, would make sense to me...

Comment: Many of the restrictions are imposed by the Store. If you don't go through Store, then the restrictions don't apply.